# How to flatten specific group in linq and select all elements, and only first from other groups

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items, where some items may have null/zero values of specific item's property. I am grouping items by other property. Then all I want, is to select First() element of those groups where my property != null/zero, and all the items in group where that property equals null/zero. How to do that?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear at the moment. You might want to try to put some sample code in along with some desired input and output to clarify.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no relevant data and code in your question, let me give you a general answer by example:

First, let's have an example class:

```
class Test
{
    public int? First { get; set; }
    public int? Second { get; set; }
    public int? Third { get; set; }
}
```

... then let's fill it:

```
        List<Test> list = new List<Test> 
        {
            new Test {First = null, Second = 1, Third = 2},
            new Test {First = 5, Second = 3, Third = 4},
            new Test {First = 6, Second = null, Third = 8},
            new Test {First = null, Second = 2, Third = 5},
            new Test {First = 8, Second = null, Third = 14},
            new Test {First = 21, Second = 2, Third = null},
            new Test {First = 5, Second = 4, Third = 2},
            new Test {First = 9, Second = 0, Third = 8}
        };
```

... now you can do something (if I understood your question right) like this:

```
        var result = list
            .GroupBy(x => x.First) //grouping by First property
            .Select(y => new
                               {
                                   FirstNonNull = y.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Second != null), // first null in group by Second property
                                   AllNull = y.Where(f => f.Second == null) // all null in group by Second property
                               }
            );
```